# TextOutput a certain column from data frame using grep search

Tags: r, dataframe

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput(
    inputId = "team_numSearch", label = "Choose a team"),
  verbatimTextOutput("teamData")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  df <-read.csv(file = "sample.txt", head = TRUE)

  output$teamData <- renderPrint({
    df[grep(input$team_numSearch, df$Team.Number),]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

df

```
Team.Number,Match.Number
1,8888
2,2333
3,365
```

What I want is for this code to narrow down the output more to just show the Match Number. So if I search for Team.Number `1` I want an output of just `8888` not `1,8888`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the column you want to display, in your example is just ,2] int the slicing

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput(
    inputId = "team_numSearch", label = "Choose a team"),
  verbatimTextOutput("teamData")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  df <-read.csv(file = "sample.txt", head = TRUE)

  output$teamData <- renderPrint({
    df[grep(input$team_numSearch, df$Team.Number),2]
  })

}
```

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)